# three argument filtering

Tags: python

Lets assume I have defined function:

```
def threeArgs(x,y,z):
  return ... # Returns True or False
```

I also have a list of elements:

```
a = [elem1, elem2, ..., elemN]
```

I would like to construct another list b containing first and last element form list a and those elements Xn in between for which threeArgs(Xn-1,Xn, Xn+1) returns true.

How to do it in elegant pythonic way?

Comment: Please provide some code showing that you gave it at least a try yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slicing to create three shifted lists, then [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) them together:

```
[a[0]] + [y for x, y, z in zip(a, a[1:], a[2:]) if threeArgs(x, y, z)] + [a[-1]]
```

Comment: I think `[t[1] for t in zip(...) if threeArgs(*t)]` looks a little nicer, but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998381/624900) function defined, you can do this:

```
a[0] + [a[i+3] for i,v in enumerate(imap(threeArgs, window(a, 3))) if v] + a[-1]
```

which might use less memory for large lists since it's entirely iterators.