# Is there a function which will help me split (x) in a string with each split including the (x+1)th value?

Tags: python

I'm just trying to understand how to make a value after value x (i.e. x+1) in a string be included in a split.

I've tried a for loop, of just `for i: splitlist.append(i)` and can end up printing [A, B, C, D, E].

```
samplestring = 'ABCDE'
for i in samplestring:
    splitlist = []
    if i+1 == (none):
        break
    else:
        splitlist.append(i,i+1)
```

I want to return ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE'] but instead end up with a type error in the line ;

`if i+1 == (none):`.

> (TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str)

Comment: As you iterate on `samplestring` in your for loop, `i` will take the value of each letter of samplestring, and you can't add 1 to a letter.

Comment: Loop over the length of the string minus one with an index, use that index to get the current (at the index) and the next (index plus one) character from the string. Append as single string to the list.

Comment: I think you can remove the whole thing with your `None`. i can't see why you would need it. Moreover, I think you mean `None` instead of `(none)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6998245/1025391 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/1025391

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to group adjacent items together:

```
[f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(samplestring, samplestring[1:])]
```

**Example**:

```
samplestring = 'ABCDE'

print([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(samplestring, samplestring[1:])])
# ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

- you're creating an empty list every iteration
- you're trying to combine a string: `i` with an integer: `1`.
- your way of checking if the string ended is a little weird, you know the length of the string (using `len(samplestring)`), so you can dictate how often you are to loop over it

To fix this you can use:

```
samplestring = 'ABCDEF'
splitlist = []
for i in range(len(samplestring) - 1):
    splitlist.append(samplestring[i] + samplestring[i+1])
```

This results in splitlist:

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print([samplestring[i:i + 2] for i in len(samplestring) - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for Error - You are adding string and integer

```
sample = 'ABCDE'

print([sample[i]+sample[i+1] for i in range(0,len(sample)-1)])
```