# Startswith for lists in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Is there an equivalent of starts with for lists in python ?

I would like to know if a list a starts with a list b. like

```
len(a) >= len(b) and a[:len(b)] == b ?
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? There is not so much to optimize.

Comment: @Christian, it would not be wrong to do the same with strings as well, but there is an API

Comment: I don't think there's anything way simpler than that.

Comment: @ElefEnt, I think you can do the same with strings too, and pretty much any iterable

Comment: And how do you think the methods in an API are implemented?

Comment: @cnluzon I know I was just answering to the comment above, saying that though it's already simple there is still something better, for strings

Comment: I see what you mean now. I somehow did not get it exactly like that when I read it. I do not know for sure if such functionality does not exist. However, I find your solution already simple enough not to need it. But I guess that's also a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6):

You can just write `a[:len(b)] == b`

if len(b) > len(a), no error will be raised.

Comment: you mean len(b) <= len(a)?

Comment: No error will be raised in any situation. Slicing past the length of the list will not fail.

Comment: it's true, but the condition should be met in order for it to work properly

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. It will work for `len(a) < len(b)`, `len(a) == len(b)`, and `len(a) > len(b)`. The former will always be `false`, but the code will work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Tim: `False`, not `false`. This is Python, not Java (or any other language where boolean constants start with a lowercase letter.)

Answer (score 0):

For large lists, this will be more efficient:

```
from itertools import izip
...
result = all(x==y for (x, y) in izip(a, b))
```

For small lists, your code is fine. The length check can be omitted, as [DavidK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905458/142637) said, but it would not make a big difference.

PS: No, there's no build-in to check if a list starts with another list, but as you already know, it's trivial to write such a function yourself.

Answer (score -1):

it does not get much simpler than what you have (and the check on the lengths is not even needed)... 
for an overview of more extended/elegant options for finding sublists in lists, you can check out the main answer to this 
post : [elegant find sub-list in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list)