# Unexpected behaviour in Python OrderedSet.issuperset()

Tags: python, set, set-theory

I have two OrderedSets and I'm trying to check whether one in a subset of the other - both the elements and their order is important. However, the orderedset package is giving me strange results.

```
>>> import orderedset
>>> a = orderedset.OrderedSet([433, 316, 259])
>>> b = orderedset.OrderedSet([433, 316, 69])
>>> a.issuperset(b)
True
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because `b` contains a value (`69`) that is definitely not in `a`. Why is `a` a `superset` of `b` then?

However, when I try this:

```
>>> c = orderedset.OrderedSet([1, 2, 3])
>>> d = orderedset.OrderedSet([1, 2, 4])
>>> c.issuperset(d)
False
```

This behaviour seems inconsistent to me: why should the choice of values - `[433, 316, 259]` versus `[1, 2, 3]` - in the OrderedSet affect the output of `issuperset()`?

Perhaps there's a better way to do this? I need to know whether the elements in `b` are contained in `a` in the same order. Meaning that, if

```
a = OrderedSet([433, 316, 259])
```

I'm looking for partial matches within that set that start with the same starting value as `a` (`433`). This is what I want out of it:

```
OrderedSet([433, 316, 259])
OrderedSet([433, 316]])
OrderedSet([433])
```

And not:

```
OrderedSet([433, 259])
OrderedSet([316, 259])
OrderedSet([433, 316, 69])
OrderedSet([433, 259, 316])
OrderedSet([259, 433])
...
```

Basically, if this really confusing - I have an ordered set and I'm trying to find partial matches both in terms of the values and their order.

Comment: I don't think `issuperset` is going to work properly here -- it usually assumes sorted sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are using this [third party module](http://orderedset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) since Python doesn't have a built-in orderedset.

A quick look through the [source code on github](https://github.com/simonpercivall/orderedset/blob/master/lib/orderedset/_orderedset.pyx#L257) shows that the `issuperset` function is implemented as

```
def issuperset(self, other):
    return other <= self
```

Taking a look at how the less than or equal operator is defined for orderedset:

```
def __le__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, _OrderedSet):
        return len(self) <= len(other) and list(self) <= list(other)
```

So essentially, when comparing two ordered sets they are first converted to lists, and then the Python built-in `<=` is used to compare the two lists. When you compare two lists using `<=`, it's similar to a lexical string comparison meaning it compares matching indices of both lists.

According to their implementation, `[433, 316, 259]` is a superset of `[433, 316, 69]` (all matching indices of the first list are greater that or equal of the second list), whereas `[433, 316, 259]` would not be a superset of `[433, 316, 260]` (the second list has a bigger value in its last index than the first list).

What they probably wanted to write was

```
return len(self) <= len(other) and set(self) <= set(other)
```

Which would use the `<=` defined for the built-in Python sets, and properly test for subsets and supersets.

You may want to [report this issue here](https://github.com/simonpercivall/orderedset/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the problem now. I guess part of it is that defining superset/subset for an ordered set is ambiguous. I guess I should write something that is specifically suited to my needs rather than rely on an external definition. I'll report the bug so that they know about it.

If you have a suggestion for how I implement this (helpful constructs, etc.), I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you care about order when testing for superset or subset? By definition a set has no order, so this behaviour is undefined really.

Comment: I'm interested in order as much as membership - I'd like to know how many partial matches there are to my ordered set. So in the example, `[433, 316, 259]` represents a sequence of actions that users did on a website. I'd like to know, for instance, how many users completed the entire set of actions, how many completed just the first 2 actions in the sequence `[433, 316]`, and how many just stopped after completing the first `[433]`. Perhaps there's a better way to represent this information and process it?

Comment: Based on your updated question, it seems that you don't really need the properties of a set, you just want ordering. In that case you could just use a list. Your problem seems to boil down to "does a sublist exist in a list". If that's the case, try taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list