# Find the position of sublist in a list in python

Tags: list, matching, sublist

For example, I have two list x and y in Python. Supposing `x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `y = [3,4,5]`, it is clear that y is a sublist of x and the position of sublist y in x is `3`. In other words，I'm trying to get a function that judges whether a list is a sublist in another list. If so,I would like to figure out the position of the sublist as well.

I don't know if there has any off-the-shelf function I can use. If not, does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve it using some effective method.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elegant find sub-list in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [3,4,5]

occ = [i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == y[0]]

for b in occ:
      if x[b:b+len(y)] == y:
           print 'YES-- SUBLIST at : ', b
           break
      if len(occ)-1 ==  occ.index(b):
           print 'NO SUBLIST'
           break
```

Comment: Many thanks！Could you tell me why there is a “pass”in your method（line 11）. I am confused whether it is necessary.

Comment: thanks for the correction. and yes it was not necessary.

Comment: How quick you reply！Thank you for your help:)