# What is the similar python code for this matlab code " find( conv ( variable, [1 0 1] == 2 ) ) ", where variable is a list of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matlab

I have a list

```
series = [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 .....]
```

I wish to find the indices where two 1's are separated by 2 indices ex. [0 1 0 1] now the location is 1 and 3. Now I wish to do the same for bigger list.

Matlab code for this purpose is

```
find(conv(series,[1 0 1])==2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620085/find-the-position-of-sublist-in-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1):

see below.

is that what you are looking for?

```
s = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
data = []
for x in range(0,len(s)-1):
    if x > 0:
        if s[x-1] == 1 and s[x] != 1 and s[x+1] == 1:
            data.append(x)
print(data)
```

output

```
[3, 5]
```

Comment: I' am looking for more elegant way.