# Find the first index of consecutive values in correct order in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and list of values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4]}, index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/06/2020'))
values_to_find = [4, 6, 2]
```

```
            A
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-02  4
2020-01-03  6
2020-01-04  2
2020-01-05  7
2020-01-06  4
```

I want to get the index (iloc) of the first value 4 in the dataframe if the next two rows in the dataframe has values 6 and 2. In this case, the desired output is 2 as it is the second index (iloc) in the dataframe.

I tried using `np.flatnonzero(df['A'] == values_to_find)` but `np.flatnonzero()` only works with a single value, otherwise `values_to_find` must be of the same size as the dataframe.

Comment: Have you read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100242/python-numpy-first-occurrence-of-subarray)?

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in two steps:

1. Find where the sequence of values happen. We'll use `df.rolling` to iterate a window of 3 consecutive rows. Then, we'll use `.apply` to find where the condition is True (is this array of values equal to the sequence we're looking for?). Consider that `values_to_find` should be a `np.array` (`np.array(values_to_find)`):

   ```
   >>> df_condition = df.rolling(3).apply(lambda g: all(g.astype(int) == values_to_find), raw=False)
   >>> df_condition
                 A
   2020-01-01  NaN
   2020-01-02  NaN
   2020-01-03  0.0
   2020-01-04  1.0
   2020-01-05  0.0
   2020-01-06  0.0
   ```
2. Find the index where the condition is True for the first time. We'll just compare the values in the "A" column to 1 and locate the index of the first row that matches this condition:

   ```
   >>> df.loc[df_condition["A"] == 1].iloc[0]
   A    2
   Name: 2020-01-04 00:00:00, dtype: int64
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622226/13043216), the following function may help you:

```
def find_sub_loc(x,y):
  occ = [i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == y[0]]
  for b in occ:
        if x[b:b+len(y)] == y:
            return (b+1)
            break
        if len(occ)-1 ==  occ.index(b):
            return -1
            break
```

Example: In your case `find_sub_loc(list(df.A.values), values_to_find)` will return the index value `2`