# Python 3.5: search different values in a list

Tags: python, string, list, search

I have a list:

```
myList = [abc123, def456, ghi789, xyz999]
```

I need to search specific values in myList, based on this "sub-list" of allowed values:

```
allowed = [abc123, xyz999]
```

Edit: **I need to check if myList contains the values in allowed**

I already know how to seach for a specific substring in a list but I don't really understand how to do the same with a "sub-list".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elegant find sub-list in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list)

Comment: What do you mean by "search"? Do you want to check if `myList` contains the values in `allowed`? Or do you want to find their index in `myList`? Please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Yes, I want to check if myList contains the values in allowed.

Comment: @PantsuJo So what's the expected output? `[True, True]` or maybe just `True` or something else?

Comment: Just "true", a confirm that the allowed values exist in myList.

Comment: looks like you checking not allowed, but instead mandatory values.

Comment: Or swap the lists (larger for allowed, smaller for observed)

Comment: Or may be: You need to check if myList contains ONLY the values from allowed, or may be You need to check if myList contains ALL the values from allowed, or may be You need to check if myList contains AT LEAST one values from allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think you mean to look if the allowed values are in your list. So try this:

```
myList = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'xyz999']
allowed = ['abc123', 'xyz999']

for i in myList:
    if i in allowed:
        print("{0} in the list".format(i))
```

After reading your comments, the question is a bit vague,
I made a solutions using a Dictionary to store the values of allowed and check wether all of them are in myList

```
myList = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'xyz999']
allowed = {'abc123' : False, 'xyz999' : False}

for i in myList:
    if i in allowed:
        allowed[i]=True

print((all(value == True for value in allowed.values())))
```

Comment: Perfect solution, working for me! Sorry for being not so clear in my explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set.issubset`:

```
>>> set(allowed).issubset(myList)
True
```

Or, if your values aren't hashable, `all` with a comprehension:

```
>>> all(value in myList for value in allowed)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in myList:
    if value in allowed:
        #dosomething
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming string lists (i.e. hashable):

`set(a).intersect(set(b))` yield common elements

if need only boolean use `issubset` method:
[Python - verifying if one list is a subset of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other)

for indvidual item search find, index
[Python: Find in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)