# python - Comparing two lists to see if one occurs in another consecutively

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare, nested-loops

I've been trying to make a function that can take two lists of any size (say, list A and list B) and sees if list B occurs in list A, but consecutively and in the same order. If the above is true, it returns True, else it'll return False

e.g.

```
A:[9,0,**1,2,3,4,5,6,**7,8] and B:[1,2,3,4,5,6] is successful

A:[1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0] and B:[1,2,3,4,5,6] is unsuccessful.

A:[1,2,3,4,5,6] and B [6,5,3,2,1,4] fails because despite having the same 
 numbers, they aren't in the same order
```

I've tried doing this using nested loops so far and am a bit confused as to where to go

Comment: Might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list

Comment: Is this what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
L1 = [9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
L2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = 0
w = 0
for a in range(len(L2)):
   for b in range(w+1, len(L1)):
      if L2[a] == L1[b]:
        c = c+1
        w = b
        break
      else:
        c = 0
    if c == len(L2):
       print('yes')
       break
```

Here you check if the element of l2 is in l1 and if so breaks the first loops remember where you left and of the next element of l2 is the  same as the next element of l1 and so on.

And the last part is to check if this happened as much times as the length of l2. if so then you know that the statement is correct!

Comment: Thank you. I was trying something alongside with the captions but couldn't wrap my head around what the indexes ought to be.

Comment: No problem if this works then please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

i converted the entire list into a string and then found a substring of that string

the list when converted to a string it becomes

```
str(a)='[9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]'
```

which when when we strip the string becomes

```
str(a).strip('[]')='9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'
```

Now the problem just converted to

checking if there is a substring in the the string 
so we can us the in operator to check the substring

**The solution**

```
a=[9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(str(b).strip('[]') in str(a).strip(']['))
```

[testcase1](https://eval.in/926200)

[testcase2](https://eval.in/926198)

Answer (score 0):

if your arrays are not huge and if you can find a way to map each element in your array to a string you can use:

```
list1 = [9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

if ''.join(str(e) for e in list2) in ''.join(str(e) for e in list1):
    print 'true'
```

it just make two string from the lists and than use 'in' to find any accorence

Answer (score 0):

Use any function

```
any(A[i:i+len(B)] == B  for i in range(len(A) - len(B) + 1))
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/926186)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
L1 = [9,2,1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8]
L2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def sameorder(L1,L2):
    for i in range(len(L1)-len(L2)+1):
        if L1[i:len(L2)+i]==L2:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create sublists of `a` that can be analyzed:

```
def is_consecutive(a, b):
   return any(all(c == d for c, d in zip(b, i)) for i in [a[e:e+len(b)] for e in range(len(a)-len(b))])

cases = [[[9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4]]]
final_cases = {"case_{}".format(i):is_consecutive(*a) for i, a in enumerate(cases, start=1)}
```

Output:

```
{'case_3': False, 'case_2': False, 'case_1': True}
```