# How to find out if certain values are contained in a list, order matters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',1,1,0]

b = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',0,1,1]
```

`pattern = ['yes',1,1]` #The main lists a and b should check for the pattern in the same order

I'm expecting an output like:

pattern in a - should give 'Yes' or True

pattern in b - should give 'No' or False

Merging the values in the list to form 1 string and checking with an if - in condition is not the path I'm looking for.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list

Comment: I've tried to loop through both like one loop within the other, but it loses sense of the pattern and starts checking for individual elements.

Comment: How is this different than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` with a generator comprehension and list slicing:

```
a = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',1,1,0]
b = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',0,1,1]
pattern = ['yes',1,1]

def comparer(L, p):
    n = len(p)
    return any(L[i:i+n] == p for i in range(len(L)-n))

comparer(a, pattern)  # True
comparer(b, pattern)  # False
```

Comment: Oh! This works perfectly. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @nisha21_m also, unlike the other answer, this will maintain `type` integrity as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',1,1,0]
>>> b = [1,1,0,0,0,'yes',0,1,1]
>>> pattern = ['yes',1,1]
>>> 
>>> tuple(pattern) in zip(*[a[i:] for i in range(len(pattern))])
True
>>> 
>>> tuple(pattern) in zip(*[b[i:] for i in range(len(pattern))])
False
>>>
```

Comment: No need for the intermediary list creation: `tuple(pattern) in zip(*(a[i:] for i in range(len(pattern))))`.