# How to find indices of two lists intersection using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, intersection

I have 2 lists:

> ```
> l1 = ['oak', 'tree', ',', 'tree', 'preservation', 'order', 'to',
>  'be', 'crowned', 'and', 'cleared', 'of', 'deadwood']
> l2 =  ['tree', 'preservation', 'order']
> ```

I need to find indices of intersection of these. Result should be just a list of`[3,4,5]`.

The problem is algorithms I found returns wrong values. For example:

```
def find_matching_indices(a, b):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(b):
            if x == y:
                yield i, j
```

returns `[(1, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 2)]` so it consideres all matches not the whole list within list.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect [1, 3, 4, 5]?

     [i for i, val in enumerate(l1) if val in l2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elegant find sub-list in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list)

Comment: @lil_solbs I think they're looking for `l2` to be present in its entirety as a sublist of `l1`.

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697438/9754169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.deque` with a maximum length of the size of `l2` and enqueue items of `l1` into it to act as a rolling window. Output the current index plus the ones before it up to the length of `l2` if the content of the queue matches that of `l2`:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque(maxlen=len(l2))
for i, s in enumerate(l1):
    q.append(s)
    if list(q) == l2:
        print(list(range(i - len(l2) + 1, i + 1)))
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested many solutions and I think it's optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient algorithm, but you can do:

```
l1 = ['oak', 'tree', ',', 'tree', 'preservation', 'order', 'to',
 'be', 'crowned', 'and', 'cleared', 'of', 'deadwood']
l2 =  ['tree', 'preservation', 'order']

def intersection(l1, l2):            
    for i in range(len(l1)-len(l2)+1):
        if l1[i:i+len(l2)] == l2:
            return [j for j in range(i, i+len(l2))]

print(intersection(l1, l2))
# [3, 4, 5]
```

It just compares the short `l2` list with successive slices of `l1`. When they match, it creates the list of matching indices.