# Python: How to check if an array is contained in another array using `numpy.all`and `numpy.any`?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-image

I am working on detecting certain areas on an image using `scikit-image`. I was able to detect blobs using `blob_doh` function. Also I was able to find regions using `Canny edge detector` and labeling.

Now I want to check if the blobs, which I found before, are inside of those regions, and sort out those blobs which are not in any of the regions. Then I want to draw only the blobs which are inside the regions.

I was trying to implement this using `numpy.all` and `numpy.any` but I probably misunderstand the way these functions work. Here is what I have:

```
for region in regions:
    # list of pixels' coords in a region
    pixel_array = region.coords

    # check if a blob is inside the region
    for blob in blobs_doh:
        y, x, r = blob

        if np.any(pixel_array == [x, y]):
            c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color='red', linewidth=1, fill=False)
            minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
            rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr - minr, fill=False, edgecolor='lime', linewidth=1)
            # draw blobs and regtangles
            ax.add_patch(c)
            ax.add_patch(rect)
            break
```

So, what I do. `region` is an array of the shape `[[a1, b1], [a2, b2], [a3, b3], ..., [an, bn]]`, and a `blob` is an array of the shape `[c, d]`. My idea was to check if there is any sub-array in `region` equal to `blob`. I could do it of course in trivial way searching in a loop, but I thought there is more efficient way of doing this, and tried to use `numpy.all` and `numpy.any`. Unfortunately, I cannot get it working correctly. The line `np.any(pixel_array == [x, y])` checks for only the first element of `blob` but not for the sub-array `[x, y]` as a whole. I also tried different combinations of `.any` and `.all` using `axis` argument:

```
np.any(pixel_array == [x, y], axis = 1).all(axis = 0)
```

but could not get any acceptable result.

Please help me with this task. What is the better way of performing such a check?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15068334/2375207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you convert pixel_array to a list. Not sure how efficient that would be, but this works:

```
if [x,y] in pixel_array.tolist():
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like someone has already timed lots of different options [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14766816/588071). The `tolist()` solution above isn't too bad, but the best option over a range of scenarios seems to be:

```
 if any(np.equal(pixel_array,[x,y]).all(1)):
```