# Find index of element in sub-sub-list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a = [[[0.0125, 6.6], [0.0125, 6.65], [0.0125, 6.7], [0.0125, 6.75], [0.0125, 6.8]], [[0.0185, 6.6], [0.0185, 6.65], [0.0185, 6.7], [0.0185, 6.75], [0.0185, 6.8]]]
```

ie: `N` sub-lists (only two here) and `M` sub-sub-lists in each sub-list (five in this example). Each element/sub-sub-list is made of two floats.

I need to find the index of a given element, say `[0.0185, 6.75]`. In this case the result should be: `[1, 3]`.

I can't just apply the `.index()` operator on `a` since the element is inside one of the sub-lists and since I don't know a priori which one it is I can't loop through the sub-lists applying that operator because it will result in an error if the element is not found.

---

**Add**

I tried the answers by zhangxaochen ans DSM in a much larger array (16 sub-lists and 70 sub-sub-lists) to see which one was faster and this is what I got:

```
DSM: 4.31537628174e-05
zhangxaochen: 0.00113296508789
```

Since DSM's answer its ~26x faster, I'm selecting that one. Thanks guys!

Comment: When you write "only two here", does that mean that in reality, there will be more than two?

Comment: @Gabriel How do you expect the indices to be returned, for the nested lists?

Comment: @thefourtheye not more _nested_ sub-lists but just more of them (ie: instead of 2 sub-lists, 40; instead of 5 sub-sub-lists, 60) Perhaps I expressed myself poorly, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `next` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> a = [[[0.0125, 6.6], [0.0125, 6.65], [0.0125, 6.7], [0.0125, 6.75], [0.0125, 6.8]], [[0.0185, 6.6], [0.0185, 6.65], [0.0185, 6.7], [0.0185, 6.75], [0.0185, 6.8]]]
>>> search_for = [0.0185, 6.75]
>>> print next(((i,j) for i,x in enumerate(a) for j,y in enumerate(x) 
...             if y == search_for), None)
(1, 3)
>>> search_for = [0.0185, 99]
>>> print next(((i,j) for i,x in enumerate(a) for j,y in enumerate(x) 
...             if y == search_for), None)
None
```

But since testing equality of floats can be too sensitive, you might want to replace `y == search_for` with an `is_close(y, search_for)` function which allows some tolerance for error.  Methods using `is in` or `.index` can't really handle that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP just commented that the lists can be nested more deeply.

Comment: No, the lists won't be nested more deeply. I said there can be _more_ sub-lists and sub-sub-lists (end even elements inside those sub-sub-lists) but not nested inside each other, just their number can increase.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to use `numpy` to do this:

```
In [93]: from numpy import *
    ...: a = [[[0.0125, 6.6], [0.0125, 6.65], [0.0125, 6.7], [0.0125, 6.75], [0.0125, 6.8]], [[0.0185, 6.6], [0.0185, 6.65], [0.0185, 6.7], [0.0185, 6.75], [0.0185, 6.8]]]
    ...: a=np.asarray(a)
    ...: needle=[0.0185, 6.75]
    ...: idx=nonzero(all(a==needle, axis=-1))
    ...: asarray(idx)[:,0]
    ...: 
Out[93]: array([1, 3])
```

I refered to these posts:

[Python/NumPy first occurrence of subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100242/python-numpy-first-occurrence-of-subarray)

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269

In this way it could handle **deeply nested** cases, e.g. `a=[[[[your data...],[...]]]]` is 4 level nested, the expected output index is `(0,1,3)` now:

```
In [95]: from numpy import *
    ...: a = [[[[0.0125, 6.6], [0.0125, 6.65], [0.0125, 6.7], [0.0125, 6.75], [0.0125, 6.8]], [[0.0185, 6.6], [0.0185, 6.65], [0.0185, 6.7], [0.0185, 6.75], [0.0185, 6.8]]]]
    ...: a=np.asarray(a)
    ...: needle=[0.0185, 6.75]
    ...: idx=nonzero(all(a==needle, axis=-1))
    ...: asarray(idx)[:,0]
Out[95]: array([0, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `next` and a generator expression:

```
search = [0.0185, 6.75]

gen = ((ix,iy) for ix,outer in enumerate(a) for iy,inner in enumerate(outer) if inner == search)

next(gen,'not found')
Out[27]: (1, 3)
```

If the generator is exhausted without finding a result, `next` returns its second argument (`'not found'` in this case, use whatever you'd like to use)

If the nested list comp above is confusing to you, it is syntactically equivalent to:

```
for ix,outer in enumerate(a):
    for iy,inner in enumerate(outer):
        if inner == search:
            yield (ix,iy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for membership using `in` before you call `.index()`.

```
def find(lst, needle):
    for i, sublist in enumerate(lst):
        if needle in sublist:
            return [i, sublist.index(needle)]

a = [[[0.0125, 6.6], [0.0125, 6.65], [0.0125, 6.7], [0.0125, 6.75], [0.0125, 6.8]], [[0.0185, 6.6], [0.0185, 6.65], [0.0185, 6.7], [0.0185, 6.75], [0.0185, 6.8]]]
element = [0.0185, 6.75]

print(find(a, element))
```

Result:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: `in` and `index`, they both are `O(N)`

Comment: @thefourtheye That's true... is there a faster way? If the data isn't sorted or otherwise structured, you have to read every element until you find the one you're looking for, don't you?

Comment: @thefourtheye But they are both built-in methods, which means they iterate over the list much faster than a python loop. However it's true that `senshin` could have just used `sublist.find(needle)` and avoid the extra iteration. Or `sublist.index(needle)` inside a `try` block.