# I have a list with sublists. Is there a way of searching for a specific elements position and return the index number of that specific sublist

Tags: python, list, function, loops

```
sublist = [[32,999,15,329,679],[1738,100,55,1800,1469],["bruges","manchester","bristol","edinburgh","barcelona"]["Vienna","Stockholm","Berlin",Prague,"Dublin"]]
```

These sublists purposely have a mix of strings and integers for example but with 6 more sublists. Is there a way to search for example "Vienna" and return 4 as in "Vienna"  is in the fourth sublist.

Many thanks

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262994/find-index-of-element-in-sub-sub-list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = next((i for i, lst in enumerate(sublist) if 'Vienna' in lst), None)
```

In your specific case `3` is returned. If no suitable sublist is found (i.e., no sublists contains 'Vienna'), then `None` is returned.

Comment: thank you for this , this is been a great help, however i made a mistake and forgot that indexes start at zero making Vienna return 3, is there a way to edit your result variable to return 3 instead outside of just result minus 1. Cheers

Comment: @HusslinHustla Fixed, now the code correctly returns 3 as a result

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one level, you can just loop through this list and check whether the element is in this list, using the `in` keyword.

If, however, you have nested sublists with several levels, you might want to use a recursive function to scan all of them. The function `finder()` below scans through all nested lists and returns the indices of the lists in which the element was first encountered:

```
sublist = [[32,999,15,329,679],
           [1738,100,55,1800,1469],
           ["bruges","manchester","bristol","edinburgh","barcelona"],
           ["Vienna","Stockholm","Berlin","Prague","Dublin"],
           ["Dog",["Cat","Parrot"]]]

def finder(nested,element):
    for i in range(len(nested)):
        if type(nested[i])==list:
            f = finder(nested[i],element)
            if type(f)==list:
                return [i]+f
        elif nested[i]==element:
            return [i]

print(finder(sublist,"Vienna"))
print(finder(sublist,"Parrot"))


#Output:
#[3, 0]
#[4, 1, 1]
```

The output means that "Vienna" is in list 3, the 0th element. The element "Parrot" was in list 4, within list 1, the 1th element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate function to elegantly solve your problem. However, keep in mind that Python uses 0-based indexing for arrays, so if you want to return 4 for "fourth sublist", you will need to add 1.

```py
def find(nest, elem):
  for idx, lst in enumerate(nest):
      if elem in list:
          return idx

sublist = [
  [32,999,15,329,679],
  [1738,100,55,1800,1469],
  ["bruges","manchester","bristol","edinburgh","barcelona"],
  ["Vienna","Stockholm","Berlin","Prague","Dublin"]]
print(find(sublist, "Vienna"))
```

To return 4:

```py
def find(nest, elem):
  for idx, lst in enumerate(nest):
      if elem in list:
          return idx + 1
```