# pandas data selection from one Dataframe and creating different n Dataframes by selecting row data in pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one Dataframe with 24 rows. 
[Dataframe image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4FB1.png)
This Dataframe is sorted according to higher rank of athlete to lower. Now I need to iterate through this Dataframe and I wanna create different 3 data frames with 8 players in each. For selection, I need to create balanced teams so I will be selecting in 1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3 pattern! I don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Seems like you already have your data in `jupyter notebook`. Please `print(dataframe)` your data and post it in your question so we can use it to help you. A picture is hard to copy.

Comment: It seems like you want to retrieve rows based on desired pattern. Please look into this similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710783/pandas-find-and-index-rows-that-match-row-sequence-pattern/49005205#49005205