# selecting data from list whiles keeping the order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

trying to select subset from a list, however the order is reversed after selection

tried using pandas isin

```
df.mon =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,...] 
 # selecting 
 results = df[df.month.isin([10,11,12,1,2,3])]
 print(results.mon]
 mon = [1,2,3,10,11,12, 1,2,3,10,11,12,...]
 desired results
 mon= [10,11,12,1,2,3,10,11,12,1,2,3,...]

 # sorting results in this
 mon = [1,1,2,2,3,3,10,10,11,11,12,12] and I dont want that either

 thanks for the help
```

Comment: But, the first `1, 2, 3` are in `[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710783/pandas-find-and-index-rows-that-match-row-sequence-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work most with basic python lists, so I have converted the df to a list.

## Data

The data is displayed in an xlsx file like this.
The input is a xlsx document which goes 1, 2, .. 12, 1, 2, .. 12 only twice, the "Values" start at 90 and count by 10 all the way out to the second 12.

[image: A portion of the xlsx file]

## Process

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
arr = df['Column'].tolist()
arr2 = df['Values'].tolist()

monthsofint = [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]

locs = []

dictor = {}
for i in range(len(monthsofint)):
    dictor[monthsofint[i]] = []

for i in range(len(monthsofint)):  # !! Assumption !!
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if monthsofint[i] == arr[j]:
            dictor[monthsofint[i]].append(j)

newlist = []
newlist2 = []
for i in range(len(dictor[monthsofint[0]])):
    for j in range(len(monthsofint)):
        newlist.append(arr[dictor[monthsofint[j]][i]])
        newlist2.append(arr2[dictor[monthsofint[j]][i]])

print(newlist)
print(newlist2)
```

Output: `[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]` and `[180, 190, 200, 90, 100, 110, 300, 310, 320, 210, 220, 230]`

Note on Assumption: The assumption made is that there will always be 12 months for every year in the file.

Comment: pretty much close except that my new list should be
[10,11,12,1,2,3, 10,11,12,1,2,3 ...] and not  [10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

Comment: Yeah I relized that give me a minute

Comment: thanks that works, so how can use this new list to subset the actual values of fro the dataframe correctly?

Comment: Can you give me more context? I am not sure I understand your question well enough to give an accurate answer.

Comment: say this my df
month      value
         1  12.214394
         2 -30.114391
         3   1.343937
         4 -29.290909
         5  22.703789
         6  14.211441
         7   5.654198
         8 -28.977440
         9   8.361656
        10  12.296993
       11  18.193127
       12 -20.491604
        1  45.214394
        2  10.885609
        3 -14.656063
        4   3.709091
        5   8.703789
        6  24.211441
        7 -46.345802
I want to use my list to get the values of each month say df[newlist]

but doest work currently

Comment: I have add `arr2` and `newlist2` to try to supply the data you were requesting. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Almost perfect except one last thing so this is my actual in month value format = 1:10, 2:-20,3:8, 10:2,11:4 , 12:-10, 1:10, 2:20, 3:4, 10:15, 11: 2, 12:20,...... 
new list copies  values this way [2, 4, -10, 10,20,8] here 10,20,8 means its starting the 1,2,3 values from the begining. But I want it to ignore tthe first 1,2,3 and so after copying the 10,11,12 values the next 1,2,3 should continue and not start from the begining of the time series. I hope you understand me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case , we using `Categorical` + `cumcount`

```
#results = df[df.mon.isin([10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3])].copy()
results.mon=pd.Categorical(results.mon,[10,11,12,1,2,3])
s=results.sort_values('mon')
s=s.iloc[s.groupby('mon').cumcount().argsort()]
s
Out[172]: 
   mon
9   10
10  11
11  12
0    1
1    2
2    3
21  10
22  11
23  12
12   1
13   2
14   3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take what we can have for each category, then use izip_longest to zip those lists.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a relatively easy and simple way to do it from another source

For those who might be interested:

```
  df[(df.index > 4) & (df.month.isin([10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]))]
```