# are values in rows of column of dataframe return true or false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input data:

```
obj  number
1    433
2    342
3    111
4    345
```

output data:

```
true
```

tried:

```
df[df['number'].isin([111,433])]
df.number.isin([111,433])
df.number.any() == 111 or 433
```

but none of them is giving me the result I'm looking for

I'm trying to parse a file and any time the number is in 1 dataframe i would like to run some special algorithm to reformat it. For example if 111 is in the numbers column i would like to add a colum with layout-name where the value 'layout1' should appear

Comment: duplicate of what? How is this exactly helping anyone? Guess what i was searching on google for 1h and didn't find an answer. So it may be that the other question has another terminologie so some of us cannot find it

Comment: reopened, because there is more questions like answered in dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, test values of scalar with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) for test at least one `True`:

```
print ((df.number == 111).any())
True
```

For test multiple values with `OR` use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `any`:

```
df.number.isin([111, 222]).any()
```

And if need test consecutive values - `111` and in next row `222`:

```
print (df)
   obj  number
0    1     433
1    2     342
2    3     111
3    4     222

print (((df['number'] == 111) & (df['number'].shift(-1) == 222)).any())
True
```

Comment: @DeepSpace - For me working nice, not sure what is problem

Comment: what if i need to search for a pattern? lets say there need to be 111 and 222 in it. not just 1 of them so instead of your recomended OR an and

Comment: @J.Doe - it is more complicated, general solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005205/2901002)

Comment: no simple way if i just need to know if 111 and 222 are in 1 dataframe? no sequencing ore something. just is it in the dataframe column or not

Comment: @J.Doe - it is `print ((df.number == 111).any() and (df.number == 222).any())`. Here is `and`, because working with one scalr from one comapring with another scalar

Comment: thank you, so if i have 100 values to check then i need to write 100 and statements?

Comment: @J.Doe - no, then use another solution, give me a sec

Comment: @J.Doe - use sets - function `issubset` like `print(set([111, 222]).issubset(set(df['number'])))`

Comment: @J.Doe - Also very nice explanation about sets is [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)

Answer (score 1):

You make it too complicated, you can here check if any of the values is `111` with:

```
(df['number'] == 111).any()
```

or shorter:

```
df['number'].eq(111).any()
```

If you want to check that two (or more values) occur in a series with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.any(df[:,None] == np.array([[111, 222]]), axis=0).all()
False
```

If the number of items to check against is relatively small, this should do the trick.

Comment: what if i would like to check for 2 values let's say 111 and 222?

Comment: @J.Doe: as in both values should be elements, or at least one?

Comment: as in the column in one row is 111 and in another row is 222