# Drop the last row in a group, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, rows

I want to drop the last row in a group based on a condition. I have done the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file')
grp = df.groupby('id')
for idx, i in grp:
   df= df[df['column2'].index[-1] == 'In']

     id     product   date
 0   220    in      2014-09-01 
 1   220    out     2014-09-03 
 2   220    in      2014-10-16
 3   826    in     2014-11-11
 4   826    out     2014-12-09
 5   826    out      2014-05-19
 6   901    in      2014-09-01
 7   901    out     2014-10-05
 8   901    out     2014-11-01
```

When i do this i simply get: 
KeyError: False

my desired output would be:

```
     id     product   date
 0   220    in      2014-09-01 
 1   220    out     2014-09-03
 3   826    in     2014-11-11
 4   826    out     2014-12-09 
 6   901    in      2014-09-01
 7   901    out     2014-10-05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want remove last `in` only per groups chain inverted mask with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) by `~` with not equal `in` with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df = df[~df['id'].duplicated() | df['product'].ne('in')]
print (df)
    id product        date
0  220      in  2014-09-01
1  220     out  2014-09-03
3  826      in  2014-11-11
4  826     out  2014-12-09
5  826     out  2014-05-19
6  901      in  2014-09-01
7  901     out  2014-10-05
8  901     out  2014-11-01
```

EDIT:

If want all possible pairs `in-out` per groups use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710783/pandas-find-and-index-rows-that-match-row-sequence-pattern), only necessary map non numeric values `in-out` to numeric by `dict`, because `rolling` not working with strings:

```
#more general solution
print (df)
     id product        date
0   220     out  2014-09-03
1   220     out  2014-09-03
2   220      in  2014-09-01
3   220     out  2014-09-03
4   220      in  2014-10-16
5   826      in  2014-11-11
6   826      in  2014-11-11
7   826     out  2014-12-09
8   826     out  2014-05-19
9   901      in  2014-09-01
10  901     out  2014-10-05
11  901      in  2014-09-01
12  901     out  2014-11-01
```

---

```
pat = np.asarray(['in','out'])
N = len(pat)

d = {'in':0, 'out':1}
ma  = (df['product'].map(d)
                   .groupby(df['id'])
                   .rolling(window=N , min_periods=N)
                   .apply(lambda x: (x==list(d.values())).all(), raw=False)
                   .mask(lambda x: x == 0) 
                   .bfill(limit=N-1)
                   .fillna(0)
                   .astype(bool)
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
             )
df = df[ma]
print (df)
     id product        date
2   220      in  2014-09-01
3   220     out  2014-09-03
6   826      in  2014-11-11
7   826     out  2014-12-09
9   901      in  2014-09-01
10  901     out  2014-10-05
11  901      in  2014-09-01
12  901     out  2014-11-01
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to iterate over each person first (therefore the groups), and then remove the last line, if it does not end on "out".
Because now I have found out how to drop the row if they are not similar to the above one: 
df = df.loc [df['profuct'].shift() != df['product']]

Comment: I think my problem maybe just changed a little bit... How can I access the last row within each column "id", and drop the row, if the column "product".eq('in')

Comment: @LouiseMa - hmmm, not understand. Mainly write you need remove last id per groups, your expected output generate `in-out` values per groups and now in comment need something else. So now I am confused, what need exactly...

Comment: hmm sorry... Okay, I tried to put in the second solution, and I get the error: 
"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Comment: @LouiseMa - OK, so can I ask something? Do you need one pair `in-out` per each group?

Comment: @LouiseMa - hmm, can you create more general input data? it means is possible first row is `out`? Is possible only one value per groups? Is possible multiple `in-out` per groups?

Comment: yes, possible first row is out.. and it is also possible that one group only have one value. And yes, there is also multiple in-out per group...

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to add `skipfooter=1` when opening the .csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skipfooter=1, engine='python')
```

Comment: @jezrael I know your answer is much better, this is only for removing the last row.

Comment: max this only removes the last row on the csv file, not as per the conditions given above.