# Flagging a row according to the various amount of neighbour values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, transactions, iteration

I got a transactional operation that produces a feed like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'action':['transacted','transacted','transacted','transacted','undo','transacted','transacted','transacted','transacted','transacted','undo','undo','undo','transacted'],
                  'transaction_count':10,20,35,60,60,60,80,90,100,10,10,100,90,90]})
```

|  | action | transaction_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | transacted | 10 |
| 1 | transacted | 20 |
| 2 | transacted | 35 |
| 3 | transacted | 60 |
| 4 | undo | 60 |
| 5 | transacted | 60 |
| 6 | transacted | 80 |
| 7 | transacted | 90 |
| 8 | transacted | 100 |
| 9 | transacted | 10 |
| 10 | undo | 10 |
| 11 | undo | 100 |
| 12 | undo | 90 |
| 13 | transacted | 90 |

The counts are in a pattern but not in a linear way. (10-20-35-60-80-90-100-10-20...)

**undo** states which transaction count is cancelled.

There can be multiple undo's for multiple cancellations.

```
# This is an initial apply, to set it up
df['is_undone']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['action']=='undo' else 0, axis=1).shift(-1)
df=df.fillna(0)  # For shift

df=df.loc[df['is_undone']==0]
df=df.fillna(0)
df=df.loc[df['action']!='undo']
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Unfortunately, it only works for single undo but not for multiple in a row. Apply does not let accessing neighbour row values and I can't think of any else solution. It should also need to calculate 300k rows, so, performance is also an issue.

Expected result is:

|  | action | transaction_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | transacted | 10 |
| 1 | transacted | 20 |
| 2 | transacted | 35 |
| 3 | transacted | 60 |
| 4 | transacted | 80 |
| 5 | transacted | 90 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification of this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58581978/9857631) might give you what you want:

### Solution

```
def undo(frame):
    d = {"transacted": 0, "undo": 1}
    condition = frame["action"].map(d).rolling(2,2).apply(lambda x: x.to_list()==[0,1]).mask(lambda x: x==0).bfill(limit=1).fillna(0)
    return frame[condition==0].reset_index(drop=True)
               
result = df.groupby("transaction_count").apply(undo).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> result
       action  transaction_count
0  transacted                 10
1  transacted                 20
2  transacted                 35
3  transacted                 60
4  transacted                 80
5  transacted                 90
```

### Explanation

`groupby` is being used to deal with each `transaction_count` separately.
As, an example, consider the case where `transaction_count` is 10.

```
frame = df[df["transaction_count"]==10]
>>> frame
        action  transaction_count
0   transacted                 10
9   transacted                 10
10        undo                 10
```

In the `undo` function, we first `map` the `action` column to a number:

```
>>> frame["action"].map(d)
0     0
9     0
10    1
```

Recognize that we want to remove rows where `0` (transacted) is immediately followed by `1` (undo). In the above, this corresponds to rows with indices `9` and `10`.

To do this, we work with 2 rows of the above frame at a time using `pd.rolling` and `lambda`:

```
>>> frame["action"].map(d).rolling(2,2).apply(lambda x: x.to_list()==[0,1])
0     NaN
9     0.0
10    1.0
```

Now,  `mask` 0s to `np.nan`, `bfill` (back-fill) exactly once, and `fillna` with `0`.

```
>>> frame["action"].map(d).rolling(2,2).apply(lambda x: x.to_list()==[0,1]).mask(lambda x: x==0).bfill(limit=1).fillna(0)
0     0.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
Name: action, dtype: float64
```

From the above, we need all rows that are not equal to `1`.
This is what is returned in the `undo` function.

Comment: This works as well, however, my pandas knowledge could not handle what is going on with the code. I will study this one as well. Thanks!

Comment: It is not the most "readable" code but once you break it down and see what's happening at every `.` in the undo function, it will make perfect sense :)

Comment: CPU times: user 33 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 33 ms
Wall time: 30.4 ms
I believe chain functions slowed it a bit down, others are faster

Comment: Added a line-by-line explanation which might help you walk through and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If `transaction count` is unique within a block. Groups can be created with:

```
df['group'] = (df['action'].eq('transacted') &
               df['action'].shift().eq('undo')).cumsum()
```

```
        action  transaction_count  group
0   transacted                 10      0
1   transacted                 20      0
2   transacted                 35      0
3   transacted                 60      0
4         undo                 60      0
5   transacted                 60      1
6   transacted                 80      1
7   transacted                 90      1
8   transacted                100      1
9   transacted                 10      1
10        undo                 10      1
11        undo                100      1
12        undo                 90      1
13  transacted                 90      2
```

Then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) can be used to remove duplicate `transaction_count` per `group`:

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(['transaction_count', 'group'], keep=False)
      .drop('group', axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True))
```

`df`:

```
       action  transaction_count
0  transacted                 10
1  transacted                 20
2  transacted                 35
3  transacted                 60
4  transacted                 80
5  transacted                 90
```

---

If not, groups can be created using an inversed pathing to create like ids which associate transactions and undos:

```
s = df['action'].shift()
m = df['action'].ne(s).cumsum()
df['group'] = (df['action'].eq('transacted') & s.eq('undo')).cumsum()
df['new'] = (
    df.groupby(['action', m]).cumcount()
        .mask(df['action'].eq('transacted'),
              df.loc[::-1].groupby(['action', m]).cumcount())
)
```

```
        action  transaction_count  group  new
0   transacted                 10      0    3
1   transacted                 20      0    2
2   transacted                 35      0    1
3   transacted                 60      0    0
4         undo                 60      0    0
5   transacted                 60      1    4
6   transacted                 80      1    3
7   transacted                 90      1    2  # Matches Undo 2
8   transacted                100      1    1  # Matches Undo 1
9   transacted                 10      1    0  # Matches Undo 0
10        undo                 10      1    0  # Undo 0
11        undo                100      1    1  # Undo 1
12        undo                 90      1    2  # Undo 2
13  transacted                 90      2    0
```

Then duplicates can be dropped among `group` and `new`:

```
df = (df
      .drop_duplicates(['group', 'new'], keep=False)
      .drop(['group', 'new'], axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
       action  transaction_count
0  transacted                 10
1  transacted                 20
2  transacted                 35
3  transacted                 60
4  transacted                 80
5  transacted                 90
```

Comment: Inversed pathing solution worked like a charm for the case. In the meanwhile, I also found a solution which I will post just in a minute. I would love to hear your opinion! Thanks a lot

Comment: CPU times: user 16.6 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 16.6 ms
Wall time: 14.8 ms -- for the second part of the solution on the example df

Comment: Yeah, this would be expensive on a small dataset. On a dataset of 1000 rows this ran much faster than the other two options.

Comment: on 41k rows:
This one:
CPU times: user 44.4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 44.4 ms
Wall time: 43.2 ms

The one I posted:
CPU times: user 106 ms, sys: 5 µs, total: 106 ms
Wall time: 105 ms

50% off. Nice : )

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Thank you for the confirmation. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['is_undone']=0
for k, v in df.groupby((df['action'].shift() != df['action']).cumsum()):
    if v['action'].max()=='undo':
        df.loc[v['action'].index[0]-v['action'].count():v['action'].index[v['action'].count()-1],'is_undone']=1
df=df.loc[df['is_undone']==0]
df.drop('is_undone',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

I found [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-group-by-consecutive-same-values-128913875dba) to have consecutive code blocks are grouped. The code runs in less than a second which is more than enough for me.

Comment: Seems great! The ranging operation looks good. On small datasets this seems to run faster than mine does. I'm going to run some tests on larger sets.

Comment: CPU times: user 10.4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 10.4 ms
Wall time: 9.32 ms - with the example dataset