# Pandas: check a sequence in one column for each unique value in another column

Tags: pandas, isin

I have a table that looks like this:

| Date | Unique id | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 2018 | 2 | 0 |
| 2019 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | 2 | 1 |

For each value in "Unique id" I want to check whether "Indicator" match a special sequence of values (say, [1,1,1])

I have tried using df.groupby(['Unique id'])['Indicator].isin([1,1,1]), but the groupby method has no isin method.

The desired output would be:

| Unique id | Sequence match |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | True |

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `rolling().apply()` like this:

```
def check_pattern(s, pattern):
    return s.eq(pattern).all()

(df.groupby('Unique id', group_keys=False)['Indicator'].rolling(3)
   .apply(check_pattern, kwargs={'pattern':(1,1,1)})
   .groupby('Unique id').max().eq(1)
)
```

Output:

```
Unique id
1    False
2     True
Name: Indicator, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005205/2901002) solution for test per groups and then test if at least one value is `1` by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
a = [1,1,1]

N = len(pat)
df1 = (df.groupby(['Unique id'])['Indicator']
               .rolling(window=N , min_periods=N)
               .apply(lambda x: (x==np.asarray(a)).all())
               .eq(1)
               .groupby(level=0)
               .any()
               .reset_index(name='Sequence match'))

print (df1)
   Unique id  Sequence match
0          1           False
1          2            True
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Indicator column only has 1 and 0 values, as shown in the example, and taking inspiration from Jezrael's and Quang Hoang's answer you can try with:

```
df.groupby("Unique ID").rolling(3).apply(lambda x: True if sum(x) == 3 else False).groupby('Unique ID').max()
```

Where the lambda will return True only if the rolling sum of the 3 periods is equal to three (therefore signaling there's 3 consecutive 1's

```
           Indicator
Unique ID           
1                0.0
2                1.0
```

That when expressed in Booleans, it's equal to:

```
           Indicator
Unique ID           
1              False
2               True
```

Comment: thanks you guys, all the offered solutions work great!

Comment: hmmm, what if pattern is `1,5,3` ?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm assuming that Indicator takes only 1s and 0s as shown in the example. Being more of a flag column (True/False) rather than a numerical one that contain any integer

Comment: Indeed, the indicator only takes 1s and 0s

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
def is_sublist(y, x):
    for i in range(len(x) - len(y) + 1):
         if x[i:i+len(y)] == y:
              return True
    else:
         return False

df.groupby('Unique id').Indicator.agg(pd.Series.tolist).apply(lambda x: is_sublist([1,1,1], x))
```