# Extract relevant rows from pandas dataframe when duplicate column values are present

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

| id | left | top | width | height | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 34 | 12 | 34 | commercial |
| 2 | 99 | 42 | 99 | 42 | general |
| 3 | 1 | 47 | 9 | 4 | liability |
| 4 | 10 | 69 | 32 | 67 | commercial |
| 5 | 99 | 72 | 79 | 88 | available |

I want to **extract specific rows based on the column value** `Text`. So I want to search for certain keyphrases like `liability commercial` using `re.search` in the column `Text` and if I get a match then extract the rows i.e. 3rd and 4th row. So if the input is `liability commercial` then the output should be the following rows extracted:

| id | left | top | width | height | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 47 | 9 | 4 | liability |
| 4 | 10 | 69 | 32 | 67 | commercial |

Keep in mind that the column `Text` **may contain duplicate values**. So in the above case, there are 2 rows with the word `commerial` present.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `Keep in mind that the column Text may contain duplicate values. So in the above case, there are 2 rows with the word commerial present.` - What is algo for match? Last match?

Comment: @jezrael It depends on the keyphrase. If I want to extract `liability commercial`, then the first `commercial` should not be extracted. If I want to extract `commercial general liability` then the second `commercial` should not be extracted. Basically depends on the keyphrase we are trying to extract!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
phrase = 'liability commercial'

#match by substrings - splitted values by spaces
m = df['Text'].str.contains(phrase.replace(' ','|'))
#match by splitted values by spaces
m = df['Text'].isin(phrase.split())

#filter rows by mask and get last duplicated values in Text column
df = df[m].drop_duplicates(['Text'], keep='last')
print (df)
   id  left  top  width  height        Text
2   3     1   47      9       4   liability
3   4    10   69     32      67  commercial
```

Or if need groups by matched rows by conditions change mask, here position of splitted values ad possible duplicates not counts:

```
phrase = 'liability commercial'
m = ~df['Text'].str.contains(phrase.replace(' ','|'))
#m = ~df['Text'].isin(phrase.split())

df = df[m.cumsum().duplicated(keep=False) & ~m]
print (df)
   id  left  top  width  height        Text
2   3     1   47      9       4   liability
3   4    10   69     32      67  commercial
```

If need match by exactly matched by splitted values is possible modify [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005205/2901002):

```
phrase = 'liability commercial'

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005205/2901002
pat = np.asarray(phrase.split())
N = len(pat)


def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    c = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return c

arr = df['Text'].values
b = np.all(rolling_window(arr, N) == pat, axis=1)
c = np.mgrid[0:len(b)][b]

d = [i  for x in c for i in range(x, x+N)]
df = df[np.in1d(np.arange(len(arr)), d)]
print (df)
   id  left  top  width  height        Text
2   3     1   47      9       4   liability
3   4    10   69     32      67  commercial
```

Comment: I spent the last 24 hours trying all 3 of your solutions. The first one doesn't work outright because of the `keep = "first"/"last"`. The second solution also does not work in my case as it will extract all the duplicate words and it is impossible to separate the required ones.

Comment: @spectre - OK, so third solution working well?

Comment: For the third solution I am testing multiple scenarios and so far it is working. My only issue is that I wanted to use `regex` to search for the phrase as it is more robust. Is there any way the third solution can be modified to use `re.search`?

Comment: @spectre - Can you give me some example for using `re.search` ?

Comment: `match = re.search(r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?", flags = re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)`. Use this as an example. If there is a match then only go ahead with the third solution.

Comment: @spectre - OK, so is possible always know what number of rows are tested? E.g. for `match = re.search(r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?")` are tested 2 consecutive rows?

Comment: The words in `phrase` will always be consecutive. The number of rows tested is the total number of rows. So we will search all the rows of the dataframe for the phrase `liability commercial` using `re.search` and if there is a match then go ahead with the 3rd solution. You can use `match.group()` to get the string of the match term if you want

Comment: @spectre - yes, but I think `match = re.search(r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?", flags = re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)` - here need test 2 consecutive values - 1.+2.nd row, 2.+3rd row...

Comment: @spectre - because if test 1. value, 1.+2.nd, then 1.+2.+3.rd, ... it is possible, but slow. How many rows is in DataFrame?

Comment: `phrase = r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?"` 

and then

`match = re.search(phrase, ' '.join([i for i in d['text'].tolist() if i is not np.nan]), flags = re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)`. You can use this to search for the phrase in the text colum and if match then do 3rd solution

Comment: @spectre Hmmm. If general solution it means is possible multiple words per value? Like instead `liability` is `any liability` ?

Comment: @spectre - And for my comments above - is not possible distinguiush from phrase number of rows matched? E.g. `phrase = r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?\s.?available.?"` should be in one value, in 2 values or in 3 values?

Comment: If the phrase contains the words `any liability` then yes we have to search for the same exact words.

Comment: The number of words per row will most probably be one. So each row will contain 1 word

Comment: Also do not use `re.IGNORECASE`. Just use `re.DOTALL`!

Comment: OK, so is possible use distinguish number of consecutive words by `phrase = r".?liability.?\s.?commercial.?" N = len(phrase.split())` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254395/discussion-between-spectre-and-jezrael).