# Searching through columns for a specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column named "A" which has values like-

```
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
```

Now I want to search through this column for the pattern `0 1 0` and identify the row in column 'B' corresponding to the 1 in the column 'A'.

For example

```
'B'  'A'
 12   0
 14   0
 6    0
 3    1
 6    0
 8    0
```

Now I want it to return 3 in column 'B'.
Is there any other solution other than applying nested if else?

Comment: What do you want done for the first and last elements of `A`? They don't have both of the 0 values you're looking for, but arguably they match the pattern. Are they included or excluded?

Comment: @HansMusgrave it should match the pattern 0 1 0...so in the case of the first and last since they dont we exclude them

Comment: Got it. That kind of information should probably be included in the question btw. Is there guaranteed to only be a single row in `B` matching that pattern? If not, do you want all answers?

Comment: No there could be multiple rows matching the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy for improve performance - a bit modified solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7100242/2901002):

```
pat = [0,1,0]
N = len(pat)
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':range(4, 14), 'A':[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]})
print (df)
    B  A
0   4  0
1   5  0
2   6  1
3   7  0
4   8  0
5   9  1
6  10  0
7  11  0
8  12  1
9  13  0
```

---

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    c = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return c

arr = df['A'].values
b = np.all(rolling_window(arr, N) == pat, axis=1)

print (rolling_window(arr, N))

[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

---

```
c = np.mgrid[0:len(b)][b]
#create indices of matched pattern
print (c)
[1 4 7]

#strides by column B indexed by indices of matched pattern    
d = rolling_window(df['B'].values, N)[c]
print (d)
[[ 5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10]
 [11 12 13]]

#select second 'column'
e = d[:, 1].tolist()
print (e)
[6, 9, 12]
```

Comment: @user3483203 - Thank you.

Comment: Can I get the index of the column B also where the number was found?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob You can replace `d = rolling_window(df['B'].values, N)[c]
print (d)` to `d = rolling_window(df. index.values, N)[c]
print (d)` and then `e = d[:, 1].tolist()
print (e)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code starts by specifying the pattern you want to match. In your case, this was `0 1 0`. You also specify which coordinate in that pattern you want to correspond to the index you're pulling from column `B`. You wanted the middle element which is the `1` coordinate in a 0-based indexing scheme.

From there, we're taking column `A` and shifting it with `Series.shift()`. By default, this includes `NaN` values for missing coordinates. The `NaN` won't match with `0` or `1` or any other value of interest, so we can directly compare that shifted column to whatever we're supposed to be matching and get the exact kind of `True` or `False` values that we want.

In order to match your entire pattern, we need to combine those values with a logical AND. To do that, we reduce each shifted column pairwise with `s1 & s2`. This returns a new column which is coordinate-wise the logical AND of the originals.

Finally, we use this boolean result which is a series with as many rows as the original DataFrame `df`, and we select from `df['B']` using it. This returns a new series with just the values from `df['B']` at the intended coordinates.

```
from functools import reduce

matching_values = (0, 1, 0)
matching_index = 1

df['B'][reduce(
    lambda s1, s2: s1 & s2,
    (df['A'].shift(i)==v for i, v in zip(
        xrange(-matching_index, len(matching_values)-matching_index),
        matching_values)))]
```

If using Python 2.x, you don't need to import `reduce()` first, but in Python 3.x the `zip()` doesn't build an intermediate list, saving on CPU and RAM resources.

Depending on what you're doing, this could easily be extracted into a function exposing the relevant parameters. Magic strings of `A` and `B` probably aren't ideal and would be appropriate choices. The `matching_values` and `matching_index` are other likely candidates.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve
pat = [0,1,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':range(4, 14), 'A':[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]})
s2 = convolve(df['A'],[0,1,0],mode = 'valid')
s2 = pd.Series(s2)
df.B.iloc[s2[s2==1].index + 1].values
```

o/p:

```
array([ 6,  9, 12])
```

o/p for your given example:

```
array([3])
```

Comment: I doubt its correctness. If anyone find any please comment.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'B':range(4, 10), 'A':[0,1,0,1,1,1]})`, seems issue?

Comment: @atline what is the issue with df = pd.DataFrame({'B':range(4, 10), 'A':[0,1,0,1,1,1]})?

Answer (score 0):

Change your original data to make it suitable for more data:

```
import pandas as pd
o = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'B': [12, 14, 6, 3, 6, 8]})
b = o["A"]
m = [i+1 for (i, _) in enumerate(b) if i+2<len(b) and str(b[i])+str(b[i+1]) + str(b[i+2]) == '010']
print(o.loc[m]['B'].tolist())
```

So, for next input:

```
    A   B
0   0   12
1   1   14
2   0   6
3   1   3
4   0   6
5   0   8
```

Will output:

```
[14, 3]
```