# Check if groups of numbers in Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a Numpy array A:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20,100,200,300,500])
```

And another Numpy array B with pairs of numbers:

```
B = np.array([[2000,1000],[5000,10000],[1,1000],[300,700],[500,5],[500,700],[1,5])
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to find the index of the **first occurrence** of the pairs from B that are present in A (if available). Order of numbers within pair doesn't matter. In the example above, the numbers of pair `[500,5]` represent the first pair that is found in A.

Is there any elegant Numpy solution, without looping through each pair one by one? Appreciate any hints!

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/NumPy first occurrence of subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100242/python-numpy-first-occurrence-of-subarray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `isin` with `argmax`

```
np.isin(B,A).all(1).argmax()

Out[931]: 4

B[np.isin(B,A).all(1).argmax()]

Out[932]: array([500,   5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indexes by using [np.isin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and then considering the minimum element. The first element of the result is the index that satisfies the condition.

```
>>> np.where(np.isin(B,A).min(axis=1)==1)
(array([4, 6]),)
```

Comment: From the docs for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? This may not be efficient if you really do only care about the first true occurence

```
match_idxs = np.where(np.isin(B[:,0], A) & np.where(np.isin(B[:,1], A))
idx = matches[0] if len(matches) else None
```

Comment: From the docs for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._