# How to find dataframe inside another dataframe (order is important)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes A and B. I need to check if A has all the values in B (the order is important) and if yes I need the position.

A:

```
index    X     Y
0        0     0
1        1     0
2        1     1
3        0     1
4        0     0
5        1     1
6        2     2
7        2     1
8        2     2
```

B:

```
index    X     Y
0        0     0
1        1     1
2        2     2
```

How can I check if A contains B? In this case the answer should be yes and the starting index is 4.

Since I also need to check the order of values, the following cases will be False. (dataframe A doesn't contain them):

C:

```
index    X     Y
0        0     0
1        0     0
```

A contains C? => False

D:

```
index    X     Y
0        0     0
1        0     1
```

A contains D? => False

E:

```
index    X     Y
0        1     1
1        0     0
```

A contains E? => False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have one really fast version.
[Inspired from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100681/20037042) which deals with the same question but with 1D arrays.

```py
def findIndex(A,B):
    a=A.values # ndarray of data in A
    b=B.values # same for B
    af=a.flatten() # same ndarray, but flatten
    bf=b.flatten() # same for B
    # This create a rolling window (without actually building the array; it's just a "view") of len(bf) size from af values
    # with a "stride" (how many bytes to advance between each window) being the one of a (or b), that is the size of a line
    rollwin = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(af, shape=(len(a)-len(b)+1, len(bf)), strides=a.strides)
    # Now that we have that, we just have to find a "line" in this rolling window equal to bf. 
    lineMask=np.all(rollwin==bf, axis=1)
    if lineMask.any():
        return np.argmax(lineMask)
    else:
        return None
```

`==` here is a numpy operator, that does, real fast, comparison in all values of rollwin and b. `np.all`, with `axis=1` search for lines where all values are equal. Then `np.argmax` find the first true occurrence.

timeit says that this version is 150 times faster than my previous answer (which was already 5 times faster than a direct "for loop" approach). So, not sure it is elegant. But it is fast, and it does use vectorization power.

A variant in case dataframe is so big that memory (when creating == result. The rest are just "views") is a problem, would be to compute by batches. So, a for loop, but one that does only a fraction of real iterations. The last lines could be replaced by this batch computations

```py
BatchSize=10000
def findIndex(A,B):
    a=A.values
    b=B.values
    af=a.flatten()
    bf=b.flatten()
    rollwin = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(af, shape=(len(a)-len(b)+1, len(bf)), strides=a.strides)
    for start in range(0, len(rollwin), BatchSize):
        lineMask=np.all(rollwin[start:start+BatchSize]==bf, axis=1)
        if lineMask.any():
            return start+np.argmax(lineMask)
```

BatchSize being a parameter telling the size of the batches. The higher, the more "vectorized" are the computations, but the more memory it takes. The smaller, the closer we get to a classical for loop.

With BatchSize=10000 for example, memory usage should be really small (depending on the real number of columns), and the time similar than with the previous single batch version.

Timings with a benchmark of mine (`A=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(x,y,(n,w))); B=A[k:k+m]`, with n,w,m being size parameters, k the secret answer that should be returned by computations. x and y range for random values — the closer they are, the more "near miss" will occur)

| Version | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| np.vectorize | 164.15 |
| rollwin | 0.58 |
| Batch rollwin | 0.59 |
| bifflip's apply | 2201.71 |
| naive for loop | 657.75 |

So, those timing differences are not a "optimization vs obfuscation" tradeoff case. It is really a game changer, so, it is worth working to make it work.

With a bathsize=10000 you have a good compromise, that should not cause any memory problem, while still begin thousand time faster than easier to write version. Besides, if your jupyter crashed, it is because memory was out. If memory was out, it is because your real dataframe is way bigger than the one I've used for benchmark. And if it is so big, those timing differences will be very big also.

### Former answer

I have no elegant solution. But since nobody else seems to be posting one, let's go with what I have.

I fail to see any way to do it without a for loop. But at least, we can avoid to code the for loop ourselves, using numpy vectorize.

```py
def comp(i, a, b):
    return np.array_equal(a[i:i+len(b)], b)

vcomp=np.vectorize(comp, signature="(),(m,n),(p,n)->()")

matchPos=vcomp(np.arange(len(A)-len(B)+1), A.values, B.values)

# MatchPos is an array of boolean, with True to any position where B is found. If you want an index, you can use argmax
if matchPos.any():
    indexPos=np.argmax(matchPos)
else:
    indexPos=None
```

### Naive for loop version

Just for reference and timings, the naive for loop version

```py
def findIndex(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)-len(B)+1):
        ok=True # Will remain true if after comparing all A[i+k,j]==B[k,j] we find no diff. In which case i is the answer
        for k in range(len(B)):
             for j in range(A.shape[1]):
                 if A.iloc[i+k,j]!=B.iloc[k,j]:
                     ok=False
                     break
             if not ok: break
        if ok: return i
```

### My whole code for those experiments

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import timeit

# Note: the lower the second parameter (100), the more "near miss there are".
# Apparently, this impacts only naive for loop (which makes sense: the sooner the break occurs, the better, so
# the smaller this parameter is the worse is naive for loop)
# Beware of having r^(w×len(b)) way bigger than len(a)
# (r being the 2nd parameter of randit, and w aka a.shape[1], 2nd parameter of the range)
# Otherwise, there is a risk that a match is found sooner than expected
aa=np.random.randint(0,100,(10000,2))
A=pd.DataFrame(aa)

# B is just a slice from A. We know that 1st match should be 8000
bb=aa[8000:8005]
B=pd.DataFrame(bb)

# Vectorization method
def comp(i, a, b):
    return np.array_equal(a[i:i+len(b)], b)
vcomp=np.vectorize(comp, signature="(),(m,n),(p,n)->()")

def m1(A, B):
    return np.argmax(vcomp(np.arange(len(A)-len(B)+1), A.values, B.values))

# For loop with numpy (I havn't post it, so I haven't post timing neither)
def m2(A,B):
    for i in range(len(A)-len(B)+1):
        if np.array_equal(A.iloc[i:i+len(B)].values, B.values):
            return i
    return None

# Same. But getting array from df then slicing array, instead of slicing df the gettig array
def m3(A,B):
    for i in range(len(A)-len(B)+1):
        if np.array_equal(A.values[i:i+len(B)], B.values):
            return i
    return None

# Rolling window method
def m4(A,B):
    a=A.values
    b=B.values
    af=a.flatten()
    bf=b.flatten()
    rollwin = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(af, shape=(len(a)-len(b)+1, len(bf)), strides=a.strides)
    return np.argmax(np.all(rollwin==bf, axis=1))

# Same, but using batches of BatchSize slices of rollwin, to ensure that rollwin==bf (that creates an actual array
# of boolean, when rollwin was just a "view") is small enough to avoid memory explosion, and big enough to 
# allow good vectorization
BatchSize=10000
def m5(A,B):
    a=A.values
    b=B.values
    af=a.flatten()
    bf=b.flatten()
    rollwin = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(af, shape=(len(a)-len(b)+1, len(bf)), strides=a.strides)
    for start in range(0, len(rollwin), BatchSize):
        lineMask=np.all(rollwin[start:start+BatchSize]==bf, axis=1)
        if lineMask.any():
            return start+np.argmax(lineMask)

# bitflip's apply method
def m6(A,B):
    l=len(B)
    return np.where(A.apply(lambda row: B.equals(A[row.name:row.name+len(B.index)].reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1))

# Naive for/iloc method
def m7(A,B):
    for i in range(len(A)-len(B)+1):
        ok=True
        for k in range(len(B)):
             for j in range(A.shape[1]):
                 if A.iloc[i+k,j]!=B.iloc[k,j]:
                     ok=False
                     break
             if not ok: break
        if ok: return i
             

# Timings per 1k run (so ×100 when counted on 10 runs, ×0.1 when counted on 10k runs)
print("| Method             | Timings | Answer |")
print("| ------------------ | ------- | ------ |")
print("| np.vectorize       | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m1(A,B), number=10)*100, m1(A,B)))
print("| df.values[x:y].eq  | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m2(A,B), number=10)*100, m2(A,B)))
print("| df[x:y].values.eq  | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m3(A,B), number=10)*100, m3(A,B)))
print("| rollwin            | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m4(A,B), number=10000)*0.1, m4(A,B)))
print("| batch rollwin      | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m5(A,B), number=10000)*0.1, m5(A,B)))
print("| apply              | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m6(A,B), number=10)*100, m6(A,B)[0]))
print("| naive for .iloc    | %7.2f | %6d |"%(timeit.timeit(lambda: m7(A,B), number=10)*100, m7(A,B)))
```

Comment: On this line: `lineMask=np.all(rollwin==bf, axis=1)` Jupyter notebook fails with _The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically._

Comment: Very probably because of memory outage (this is where it could happen). I suggested a variant that should solve that

Comment: Nice answer with a lot of effort. Thanks for comparing solutions. However I cant make it work using OP's A und B. Could you please post how you use that function?

Comment: @bitflip Yes, you're right. I often ask for question to contain a minimal reproducible example, data included. That goes for answer too. I add my complete experimental code, including data generation. Note that I've also tried from the OP's dataframe (and it worked), but it was "too easy" for timings (besides, if the OP is trying to optimize timing, and, moreover, had a memory explosion, it is because their dataframe contains more millions than dozen cells)

Answer (score 0):

Probably slower than using numpy only but easily readable:

```
l = len(B.index)
A.apply(lambda row: B.equals(A[row.name:row.name+l].reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1)
```

giving you:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
```

numpy.where to get the index:

```
np.where(A.apply(lambda row: B.equals(A[row.name:row.name+len(B.index)].reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1))
```

Comment: Well, yes it is slower. 4000 times slower :-). I am often disappointed by apply (especially when I expect it to be "halfway vectorization", which it is not). Even the most naive for loop (see end of my answer) is 3 times faster than apply