# numpy: Getting a "moving maximum" array of fixed width of slices from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D-array representing a time series of size N (with index 0 being the newest value). Now I want to calculate another array that contains a moving maximum, i.e. the maximum of the last M < N values (which would have size N-M+1).

Example (X = time series, Y = desired output with max. of the last 3 values):

```
X = np.array([5,6,4,5,4,6,5,7,8,9,8])
Y = np.array([6,6,5,6,6,7,8,9,9])
```

How would I do that efficiently? I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean) using numpy's [convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)-function to calculate a running average, but I must admit I don't really understand what the convolve does and how to apply it to calculate the running max (or min).

Comment: That other question has some good idea, but they are buried in a more complicated problem.

Comment: indeed. The "windowed_view" function should already pave the way to solve my problem. I'm still new to numpy and "thinking in arrays", but the possibilities are really nice :)

Comment: A more succinct duplicate (from 2011): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy  (using the `as_strided` solution).  Found with a search for 'rolling [window]'.

Comment: The alleged duplicate is about rolling "drawdowns", not about rolling "maximums".  I didn't find this question here answered there.