# Rolling window on a circular array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, circular-list

I want to apply a given function (in particular, the np.std()) to an array of measurements,
and I'd like to apply it on a rolling window of a given size.

But - since the measurements are intended to be in a circular array - I also need the rolling window to be able to overlap from the array end to its beginning.

Therefore, I'm unable to use the answer in [Rolling window for 1D arrays in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy) ... I tried to modify its approach, but I'm not a numpy expert and I was unable to understand what np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided does (where is its documentation???)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pad the original array with enough values to make a "pseudo-circular" array. Then apply `rolling_window` to the pseudo-circular array:

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
    # http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg29450.html
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def circular_rolling_window(a, window):
    pseudocircular = np.pad(a, pad_width=(0, windowsize-1), mode='wrap')
    return rolling_window(pseudocircular, windowsize)

a = np.arange(5)
windowsize = 3
print(circular_rolling_window(a, windowsize))
```

yields

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 0]
 [4 0 1]]
```

Comment: It worked - thanks a lot! To simplify, I just inserted your line a
 = np.pad(a, pad_width=(0, windowsize-1), mode='wrap') as 1st line in the rolling_window() definition

Comment: That's a good idea; I've edited my post to use it. Since Erik Rigtorp's "rolling_window" has been cited frequently on SO, I've given the circular version a different name.