# Pandas rolling weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, weighted-average

I want to apply a weighted rolling average to a large timeseries, set up as a pandas dataframe, where the weights are different for each day. Here's a subset of the dataframe

DF:

```
Date        v_std  vertical                  
2010-10-01  1.909   545.231
2010-10-02  1.890   538.610
2010-10-03  1.887   542.759
2010-10-04  1.942   545.221
2010-10-05  1.847   536.832
2010-10-06  1.884   538.858
2010-10-07  1.864   538.017
2010-10-08  1.833   540.737
2010-10-09  1.847   537.906
2010-10-10  1.881   538.210
2010-10-11  1.868   544.238
2010-10-12  1.856   534.878
```

I want to take a rolling average of the vertical column using the v_std as the weights. I've been using the weighted average function:

```
def wavg(group, avg_name, weight_name):
    d = group[avg_name]
    w = group[weight_name]
    try:
        return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return d.mean()
```

But I can't figure out how to implement this for a rolling weighted average. I assume it is similar to

```
df.rolling(window = 7).apply(wavg, "vertical", "v_std")
```

or utilizing rolling_apply? Or will I have to write a new function all together?
Thank you!

Comment: Short answer is, you can't, directly. You _can_ however use strided tricks with numpy. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636916/how-to-access-multi-columns-in-the-rolling-operator

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `EWM.mean` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.EWM.mean.html#pandas.core.window.EWM.mean

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution for rolling weighted average, using pandas `_Rolling_and_Expanding`:

First, I've added new column for the multiplication:

```
df['mul'] = df['value'] * df['weight']
```

Then write the function you would like to apply:

```
from pandas.core.window.rolling import _Rolling_and_Expanding
def weighted_average(x):
    d = []
    d.append(x['mul'].sum()/x['weight'].sum())
    return pd.Series(d, index=['wavg'])

_Rolling_and_Expanding.weighted_average = weighted_average
```

Apply the function by the following line:

```
result = mean_per_group.rolling(window=7).weighted_average()
```

Then you can get the series you wanted by:

```
result['wavg']
```

Comment: I get ```cannot import name '_Rolling_and_Expanding' from 'pandas.core.window'```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I implemented weighted mean. Would be nice if there was a pairwise_apply for this sort of thing.

```
from pandas.core.window import _flex_binary_moment, _Rolling_and_Expanding

def weighted_mean(self, weights, **kwargs):
    weights = self._shallow_copy(weights)
    window = self._get_window(weights)

    def _get_weighted_mean(X, Y):
        X = X.astype('float64')
        Y = Y.astype('float64')
        sum_f = lambda x: x.rolling(window, self.min_periods, center=self.center).sum(**kwargs)
        return sum_f(X * Y) / sum_f(Y)

    return _flex_binary_moment(self._selected_obj, weights._selected_obj,
                               _get_weighted_mean, pairwise=True)

_Rolling_and_Expanding.weighted_mean = weighted_mean

df['mean'] = df['vertical'].rolling(window = 7).weighted_mean(df['v_std'])
```

Comment: Worked well with pandas 0.25.3. However, I add to change the import to `from pandas.core.window.rolling import _flex_binary_moment, _Rolling_and_Expanding` when passing to 1.0.3

Comment: More refactoring has happened, as of 1.1 you have to import `    from pandas.core.window.rolling import _Rolling_and_Expanding
    from pandas.core.window.common import _flex_binary_moment`

Comment: In Pandas 1.4.2, `_Rolling_and_Expanding` and  `_flex_binary_moment` do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do (pardon my long naming conventions). It is quite simple (just to take advantage of new version of Pandas's rolling.apply which added raw=False to allow passing more information than a 1d array):

```
def get_weighted_average(dataframe,window,columnname_data,columnname_weights):
    processed_dataframe=dataframe.loc[:,(columnname_data,columnname_weights)].set_index(columnname_weights)   
    def get_mean_withweights(processed_dataframe_windowed):
        return np.average(a=processed_dataframe_windowed,weights=processed_dataframe_windowed.index)
    return processed_dataframe.rolling(window=window).apply(func=get_mean_withweights,raw=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on orherman answer I created the following class that should be easier to use and has a similar API to Dataframe.rolling() :

```py
from pandas.core.window.rolling import RollingAndExpandingMixin


class RollingWeightedAverageDataFrame:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.col_names = list(df.columns)
        assert len(self.col_names) == 2,"Unexpected input, dataframe should have 2 columns"

    def rolling(self, window, min_periods):
        self.window = window
        self.min_periods = min_periods
        return self

    def weighted_average(self):
        self.df['mul'] = self.df[self.col_names[0]] * self.df[self.col_names[1]]

        def _weighted_average(x):
            return (x['mul'].sum() / x[self.col_names[1]].sum())

        RollingAndExpandingMixin.weighted_average = _weighted_average

        return self.df[[self.col_names[0], self.col_names[1], 'mul']].rolling(window=self.window, min_periods=self.min_periods).weighted_average()
```

Suppose in your code you have a dataframe with columns 'value' and 'weight', and you want a window of 7 and a minimum of 5 periods, just add the following:

```
df['wavg'] = RollingWeightedAverageDataFrame(df[['value','weight']])
                                             .rolling(window=7, min_periods=5)
                                             .weighted_average()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using numpy_ext.rolling_apply():

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_ext as npe
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "v_std", "vertical"],
                  data = ((pd.to_datetime(x[:10]), float(x[10:17]), float(x[17:]))
                          for x in
"""2010-10-01  1.909   545.231
2010-10-02  1.890   538.610
2010-10-03  1.887   542.759
2010-10-04  1.942   545.221
2010-10-05  1.847   536.832
2010-10-06  1.884   538.858
2010-10-07  1.864   538.017
2010-10-08  1.833   540.737
2010-10-09  1.847   537.906
2010-10-10  1.881   538.210
2010-10-11  1.868   544.238
2010-10-12  1.856   534.878""".split("\n"))).set_index("Date")

window = 7

# === Method 1 (less efficient)
def wavg1(vertical, v_std):
    return np.dot(v_std, vertical) / np.sum(v_std)

t = time.time()
df["wavg1"] = npe.rolling_apply(wavg1, window, df["vertical"], df["v_std"])
print(f"Method 1: {time.time()-t:6f} seconds")

# === Method 2 (more efficient but requires creating extra column)
def wavg2(v_std_vertical, v_std):
    return v_std_vertical.sum() / np.sum(v_std)

df["v_std_vertical"] = df["v_std"].mul(df["vertical"])
t = time.time()
df["wavg2"] = npe.rolling_apply(wavg2, window, df["v_std_vertical"], df["v_std"])
print(f"Method 2: {time.time()-t:6f} seconds (not counting adding new column)")

print("\n", df)
```

Output:

[image: code output]

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may be looking for win_type parameter of rolling(). You can specify different types of windows, like 'triang' (triangular) ...

You may have a look at the parameter at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: provide example on the data in question and then will be +1, link to documentation is not what SO is about