# find_peaks does not identify a peak at the start of the array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I am trying to find a vectorized approach of finding the first position in an array where the values did not get higher than the maximum of n previous numbers. I thought about using the find_peaks method of scipy.signal to find a local maximum. I think it does exactly that if you define the distance to let's say 10 n is 10. But unfortunately, the condition for the distance has to be fulfilled in both directions - previous and upcoming numbers. Is there any other method or approach to finding such a thing?

**Example:**

```
arr1 = np.array([1.        , 0.73381293, 0.75649351, 0.77693474, 0.77884614,
       0.81055903, 0.81402439, 0.78798586, 0.78839588, 0.82967961,
       0.8448    , 0.83276451, 0.82539684, 0.81762916, 0.82722515,
       0.82101804, 0.82871127, 0.82825041, 0.82086957, 0.8347826 ,
       0.82666665, 0.82352942, 0.81270903, 0.81191224, 0.83180428,
       0.84975767, 0.84044236, 0.85057473, 0.8394649 , 0.80000001,
       0.83870965, 0.83962262, 0.85039371, 0.83359748, 0.84019768,
       0.83281732, 0.83660132])

from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(arr1, distance=10)
```

In this case, it finds positions 10 and 27. But also position 0 has 10 following elements which are not higher. How can I find those?

Comment: Did either of the posted ones finally work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def get_peaks(arr, window):
    maxss = np.argmax(rolling_window(arr1, window), axis=1)
    return np.where(maxss == 0)[0]
```

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([1.        , 0.73381293, 0.75649351, 0.77693474, 0.77884614,
       0.81055903, 0.81402439, 0.78798586, 0.78839588, 0.82967961,
       0.8448    , 0.83276451, 0.82539684, 0.81762916, 0.82722515,
       0.82101804, 0.82871127, 0.82825041, 0.82086957, 0.8347826 ,
       0.82666665, 0.82352942, 0.81270903, 0.81191224, 0.83180428,
       0.84975767, 0.84044236, 0.85057473, 0.8394649 , 0.80000001,
       0.83870965, 0.83962262, 0.85039371, 0.83359748, 0.84019768,
       0.83281732, 0.83660132])
>>> get_peaks(arr1, 10)
array([ 0, 10, 27])
```

Credit for rolling window function : [Rolling window for 1D arrays in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, [`find_peaks()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) works by comparing neighboring values - so will not identify peaks that occur at the beginning or end of the array. One workaround is to use [`np.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to insert the minimum value of the array at the beginning and end, and then subtract 1 from the peaks variable:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> peaks, _ = find_peaks(np.concatenate(([min(arr1)],arr1,[min(arr1)])), distance=10)
>>> peaks-1
array([ 0, 10, 27], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`1D sliding-windowed max filter from SciPy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d.html). Also, it seems you are comparing against `n` previous elements. Since, the first element won't have any previous element, we need to make it ignore.

Hence, we would have the implementation, like so -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter1d

def peaks_previousN(a, n):
    W = (n-1)//2
    return np.flatnonzero(a[1:]>=maximum_filter1d(a, n, origin=W)[:-1])+1
```

Sample run with given sample array -

```
In [107]: peaks_previousN(arr1, n=10)
Out[107]: array([25, 27])
```

Comment: You are right. Maybe  i got confused when looking for a right way to do it. Im looking for the first position where the maximum did not changed 10 elements long. So it would be index 10. Because the maximum of 1 did not changed for 10 elements. So i think find peaks of scipy signal is exactly what im looking for.

Comment: @Varlor So, are you saying compare the current against the last 10 element including or excluding the current element?

Comment: The current against the last 10, excluding the current element. And i just need the first occurence

Comment: @Varlor Then, I think the final expected output for `n = 10`, would be `[25,27]`. `10` won't be there because `arr1[0:10].max()` is `1.0` and `a[10]` is `0.8448`. Again, `0` won't be there because there are no previous elements to it. Am I right?

Comment: 0 wouldnt be there exactly, because we are looking for the index where the overall maximum did not change n elements long. But it would be 10, because a[10] is 0.8448 and not higher than 1. So the maximum is still 1.0 and fullfiles the condition. Sorry if i was not clear enough prevously

Comment: @Varlor Thought you were looking for peak. If `a[10]`, which is `0.8448 ` is not higher or equal to the max of previous 10 elements, how can it be called a peak?

Comment: you are absoulutley right. In my way to search a vectorized solution of my problem solution i just thought to use somehow the peak function. It was a failure of me