# How can I find and match patterns in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, design-patterns

I have a large array with zeros and ones, `array = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`. How can I find matching patterns like `[0, 0]`, `[0, 1]`, `[1, 0]`, `[1, 1]` in array.

Comment: Have you tried converting it as string and use string methods?

Comment: What is your desired output when array = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0] and pattern is [1, 0]?

Comment: @GilseungAhn I am trying to count how many times these patterns repeat in the array by processing the array two elements at a time. So in this case, I have four patterns, so I would have for each pattern a counter, like counter1, counter2, and so on. So every time the pattern appears, make the counter go up for one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a convolution for that, e.g. [`numpy.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 1])

# this fixes the issue that some patterns look identical
# scores due to the multiplication with 0
# e.g. [1, 0, 1] and [1, 1, 1]
# we just replace the 0 by -1
data[data == 0] = -1


kernel = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])

# same fix for kernel
kernel[kernel == 0] = -1

res = np.convolve(data,kernel, 'full')
print(res)
# >>> [-1  0 -1  2  1  2  5 -2 -2 -2 -2  0 -5 -2  5  0 -1  2  1]

res = np.convolve(data,kernel, 'same')
print(res)
# >>> [ 2  1  2  5 -2 -2 -2 -2  0 -5 -2  5]    

res = np.convolve(data,kernel, 'valid')
print(res)
# >>> [-2 -2 -2 -2  0]
```

The higher the result the better the match. In your case is should be equal to the number of ones in your pattern and the index can be found using `np.argmax()`.

Look at the keyword `mode` (full, same, valid) and choose what is best for your case.

There is also `scipy.signal.convolve`, which might be faster if you are processing lots of data.

Comment: This solution has the same issue as @MykoloZotko had with his first. If you look for e.g. `[1, 0, 1]` you will have an equal "match" for `[1, 0, 1]` and `[1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: I added a hacky fix for this to the answer. Replacing the zeros in the kernel and the data with -1 should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811241/8973620) to create a rolling window array:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
pattern = np.array([1, 0, 1])

arr = rolling_window(arr, pattern.shape[0])
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]]
```

Then you can look for matches:

```
(arr == pattern).all(axis=1)
# [False False False False False False False False  True False]
```

Alternatively, you can use the method `rolling` in `pandas`:

```
(pd.Series(arr).rolling(pattern.shape[0])
    .apply(lambda x: (x == pattern).all())
    .fillna(0).astype('bool'))
```

Comment: But here you would find a match in `[1,1,1]` as well. Thus, it is not trying to "match" zeros, but it just "ignores" them.