# How to efficiently slide numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to slide a ND numpy array.
Currently, the code below do the work.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([np.arange(0,16), np.arange(17,33),np.arange(33,49)])
window_size=4
expected_opt=[arr [:, i:i+window_size]for i in range(0,16,window_size)]
```

But I curious whether there is more efficient way to achieve similar objective.

one might suggest [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy/6811241#6811241), but the solution gives different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a reshape, not rolling:

```
arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],-1,window_size).transpose(1,0,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [17, 18, 19, 20],
        [33, 34, 35, 36]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [21, 22, 23, 24],
        [37, 38, 39, 40]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [25, 26, 27, 28],
        [41, 42, 43, 44]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [29, 30, 31, 32],
        [45, 46, 47, 48]]])
```

Comment: Hi @Quang, thanks for the suggestion. But,the result is inconsistent if, say I changed the window_size to 2. By right, the shape should be of (8,3,2)

Comment: @balandongiv thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great, now window_size=2,4,8 give the intended result