# Optimizing Calculations with numpy and numba Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray, numba

I am trying to make python run standard deviation functions faster with numba and numpy. However the problem is the for loop is very slow and I need alternatives so that I could make the code much faster. I iterated numba to the already existing numpy version however there is not much of a gain in performance. My original `list_` has million of values within it thus it is taking a very long time to compute the standard deviation function. The `list_` function down below is a very short numpy array that is meant to be an example for my problem as I wont be able to post the original list numbers. The for loop in the function below calculates the standard deviation of every nth number defined by the variable `number` in the `list_` below. How would I be able to make this current function run faster.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit,jit,vectorize

number = 5
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
```

Normal code:

```
def std_():
    std = np.array([list_[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(list_)-number)])
    print(std)
std_()
```

Numba Code:

```
jitted_func = njit()(std_)
jitted_func()
```

performance results:
[image]

Comment: You can implement a simple for loop and calling inside `res[i]=np.std(a[i:i+window])`. If you compile this with Numba it is about as fast as numpy, without a memory overhead. A bit more advanced (and faster) would be to implement an algorithm for rolling standard deviation. eg. like described here https://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a vectorised fashion.

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def std_():
    std = np.array([list_[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(list_)-number)])
    return std

std1 = np.std(rolling_window(list_, 5), axis=1)
print(np.allclose(std1[:-1], std_()))
```

Gives `True`. The code for `rolling_window` has been taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy/6811241#6811241) answer.

Comparison with numba -

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit,jit,vectorize

number = 5
list_= np.random.rand(10000)

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def std_():
    std = np.array([list_[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(list_)-number)])
    return std

%timeit np.std(rolling_window(list_, 5), axis=1)
%%timeit
jitted_func = njit()(std_)
jitted_func()
```

Gives

```
499 µs ± 3.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
106 ms ± 2.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me a memory error `Unable to allocate 198. GiB for an array with shape (2659448, 10000) and data type float64`. As I have explained above that my main `list_` has over 2 million arrays in it.

Comment: Ananda, the OP has been stingy with information, but it appears that the `rolling_window` array is too large.  The `as_strided` array is a `view`, a 'virtual' expansion of the source. But `np.std` has to subtract the `mean` from that, producing a full size array.  `as_strided` arrays can easily blow up memory use.