# Turning loop comprehensions into numpy form

Tags: python, function, numpy, iterator, slice

Is there anyway I could convert the standard deviation function to be computed just like the `y_mean` and `xy_mean` functions. I don't want to use a for loop for calculating the standard deviation or a function that takes a lot of RAM memory. I am trying to use `np.convolve()` function for calculating the standard deviation `std`.

variables:

```
number = 5
PC_list= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
```

Vanilla python functions:

```
y_mean = sum(PC_list[i:i+number])/number
xy_mean = sum([x * (i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(PC_list[i:i+number])])/number
std = (sum([(k - y_mean)**2 for k in PC_list[i:i+number]])/(number-1))**0.5
```

Numpy versions:

```
y_mean = (np.convolve(PC_list, np.ones(shape=(number)), mode='valid')/number)[:-1]
xy_mean = (np.convolve(PC_list, np.arange(number, 0, -1), mode='valid'))[:-1]
std = ?
```

Comment: by the way it's known as *list comprehension*

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Comment: Before trying to answer this, it may be worth while scanning the OP's previous questions seeking the `std` moving windows like this.  He's been trying, over a half dozen questions, to speed up an iterative calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) and [`np.std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) with `ddof=1`:

```
>>> np.std(
        np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
            PC_list, 
            shape=(PC_list.shape[0] - number + 1, number), 
            strides=PC_list.strides*2
        ), 
        axis=-1, 
        ddof=1
    )
array([25.35313557, 11.6209317 , 16.32415133, 15.46019574, 15.29513506,
       14.02947067, 14.68620846, 17.04664993, 16.38348865, 12.9925946 ,
        9.58525968,  5.32623099, 10.61466493, 23.71209646, 27.85489139,
       23.31091745, 14.78211757, 12.11214834, 17.90301391, 15.42895731,
       11.7602241 ,  9.27171536, 12.57714149, 17.25865608, 15.2717403 ,
        9.02825105])
```

Otherwise you can move use [`pandas.Series.rolling.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html), [`pandas.Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) then [`pandas.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
>>> pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
 
array([25.35313557, 11.6209317 , 16.32415133, 15.46019574, 15.29513506,
       14.02947067, 14.68620846, 17.04664993, 16.38348865, 12.9925946 ,
        9.58525968,  5.32623099, 10.61466493, 23.71209646, 27.85489139,
       23.31091745, 14.78211757, 12.11214834, 17.90301391, 15.42895731,
       11.7602241 ,  9.27171536, 12.57714149, 17.25865608, 15.2717403 ,
        9.02825105])
```

**EXPLANATION**:
`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is used to reshape the array in a special way, that resembles rolling:

```
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
            PC_list, 
            shape=(PC_list.shape[0] - number + 1, number), 
            strides=PC_list.strides*2
        )

array([[457.334015, 424.440002, 394.79599 , 408.903992, 398.821014],   #index: 0,1,2,3,4
       [424.440002, 394.79599 , 408.903992, 398.821014, 402.152008],   #index: 1,2,3,4,5
       [394.79599 , 408.903992, 398.821014, 402.152008, 435.790985],   #index: 2,3,4,5,6
       [408.903992, 398.821014, 402.152008, 435.790985, 423.204987],   # ... and so on
       [398.821014, 402.152008, 435.790985, 423.204987, 411.574005],
       [402.152008, 435.790985, 423.204987, 411.574005, 404.424988],
       [435.790985, 423.204987, 411.574005, 404.424988, 399.519989],
       [423.204987, 411.574005, 404.424988, 399.519989, 377.181   ],
       [411.574005, 404.424988, 399.519989, 377.181   , 375.46701 ],
       [404.424988, 399.519989, 377.181   , 375.46701 , 386.944   ],
       [399.519989, 377.181   , 375.46701 , 386.944   , 383.61499 ],
       [377.181   , 375.46701 , 386.944   , 383.61499 , 375.071991],
       [375.46701 , 386.944   , 383.61499 , 375.071991, 359.511993],
       [386.944   , 383.61499 , 375.071991, 359.511993, 328.865997],
       [383.61499 , 375.071991, 359.511993, 328.865997, 320.51001 ],
       [375.071991, 359.511993, 328.865997, 320.51001 , 330.07901 ],
       [359.511993, 328.865997, 320.51001 , 330.07901 , 336.187012],
       [328.865997, 320.51001 , 330.07901 , 336.187012, 352.940002],
       [320.51001 , 330.07901 , 336.187012, 352.940002, 365.026001],
       [330.07901 , 336.187012, 352.940002, 365.026001, 361.562012],
       [336.187012, 352.940002, 365.026001, 361.562012, 362.299011],
       [352.940002, 365.026001, 361.562012, 362.299011, 378.549011],
       [365.026001, 361.562012, 362.299011, 378.549011, 390.414001],
       [361.562012, 362.299011, 378.549011, 390.414001, 400.869995],
       [362.299011, 378.549011, 390.414001, 400.869995, 394.77301 ],
       [378.549011, 390.414001, 400.869995, 394.77301 , 382.556   ]])
```

Now if we take the `std` of the above array across the last axis, to obtain the rolling `std`. By default `numpy` uses `ddof=0`, i.e. Delta Degrees of Freedom = 0, which means for `number` amount of samples, the divisor will be equal to `number - 0`. Now as you want `number - 1`, you need `ddof=1`.

Comment: In previous questions, we have already suggested `as_strided`.  While the result is a `view`, `std` does `X-X.mean()` as part of its calculation (as in his `(k - y_mean)**2`).  That will make a copy, and blow up his memory.  The OP isn't very good at explaining what he's learned from previous questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65768068/memory-error-utilizing-numpy-arrays-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757073/optimizing-calculations-with-numpy-and-numba-python

Comment: @hpaulj I see. This is quite important bit of information that was left out. Would suggest OP to, at least, link his previous posts in the question, if it seems too hard to explain.

Comment: @SayandipDutta thank you the `pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()` function is outstanding, it was what I was looking for, could  apply this to `xy_mean` and `y_mean`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta I have successfully contributed the function to my `y_mean` and `std` however I couldn't find a way to implement it to `xy_mean`. I have made a post about it here [xy_mean issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866920/implementing-pandas-function-to-numpy-functions), if it could be abbreviated to that function as well. It would be great if you can take a look at that post would appreciate it.