# Fast method for generation of the sub sequences initial data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame and I'd like to make the sub sequences of the its data

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'t' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

x = []
window = 3
for i in range(0, len(d) - window + 1):
    x.append(d[i: i + window].t.values)
    
pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['t1','t2', 't3'])
```

I receive the result like this:

```
    t1  t2  t3
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
```

It works but very slow for large DataFrame. Is it possible to make the procedure faster?

Comment: how big Dataframe are we talking about? I want to benchmark the solutions I can come up with, so I want to know with what size I should test them

Comment: approximately 1000000

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) so long as your version is `> 1.20`

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

W = 3
pd.DataFrame(sliding_window_view(d['t'], W), 
             columns=[f't{i+1}' for i in range(W)])

#   t1  t2  t3
#0   1   2   3
#1   2   3   4
#2   3   4   5
#3   4   5   6
```

Comment: This is very fast!!

Comment: I think that faster than this is impossible! But this requires `numpy` version `> 1.20`.    For older versions, one can use the `rolling_window` function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811241/17120692)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick with Pandas:

```
lst = []
df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: lst.append(x.apply(int).tolist()) or 0)
result = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst, columns=['t1','t2','t3'])
```

Here is the result:

```
   t1  t2  t3
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
```