# How to get 'n' elements before Nth index of a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want to iterate over a large list wherein I need to do some computations using `n` elements before the `Nth` index of the large list. I've solved it using the following code snippet.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    j=i+3
    data_till_i = mylist[:j]
    current_window = data_till_i[-3:]
    print(current_window)
```

I get the following from the above code snippet:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 11]
[10, 11, 12]
[11, 12, 13]
[12, 13, 14]
[12, 13, 14]
[12, 13, 14]
```

Is there any one liner or more efficient way to do the exact same thing that will take less computation time? As my list size is very large (list has length `> 100K`), I'm worried about time complexity.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

My actual list is in following format:

```
[('string_attribute',1659675302861,3544.0), ('string_attribute', 1659675304443, 3544.0).........]
```

Here, the `string_attribute` is some attribute that is same for all the time and can be excluded from the computation.

**SOLUTION:**

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
dummyList = [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j')]
rolling_window=sliding_window_view(dummyList, window_shape = 3, axis=0)
print(rolling_window)
```

The output is:

```
[[['1' '2' '3']
  ['a' 'b' 'c']]

 [['2' '3' '4']
  ['b' 'c' 'd']]

 [['3' '4' '5']
  ['c' 'd' 'e']]

 [['4' '5' '6']
  ['d' 'e' 'f']]

 [['5' '6' '7']
  ['e' 'f' 'g']]

 [['6' '7' '8']
  ['f' 'g' 'h']]

 [['7' '8' '9']
  ['g' 'h' 'i']]

 [['8' '9' '10']
  ['h' 'i' 'j']]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is called a **rolling window** operation. If you want to work on `list` type specifically, there is a shorter formulation using `islice` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator):

```
window_size = 3

for i in range(len(mylist) - window_size + 1):
    print(mylist[i: i + window_size])
```

If your data is numerical, as in the example, I'd rather propose to use `numpy` as this will give you much better performance! Using the proposal from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy), your example becomes:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

sliding_window_view(np.array(mylist), window_shape = 3)
```

To give you a feeling for the timing, we can turn the options above into functions, create a much longer list, and compare the timing using `timeit` e.g. in Jupyter:

```
def rolling_window_using_iterator(list_, window_size):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(list_) - window_size + 1):
        result.append(list_[i: i + window_size])
    return result


def rolling_window_using_numpy(list_, window_size):
    return sliding_window_view(np.array(list_), window_shape = 3)


long_list = list(range(10000000))

%timeit rolling_window_using_iterator(long_list, 3)
%timeit rolling_window_using_numpy(long_list, 3)
```

prints (on my machine):

```
1.8 s ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
422 ms ± 967 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: `rolling_window_using_numpy` is super fast. I added `axis=0` after `window_shape` to make compatible with my data. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view)

```py
import numpy as np

n = 3
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(mylist, n)
out = np.append(window, [window[-1] for _ in range(n-1)], axis=0)
```

```
print(out)

[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 2  3  4]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [ 8  9 10]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [10 11 12]
 [11 12 13]
 [12 13 14]
 [12 13 14]
 [12 13 14]]
```

For one liner, if your Python version is greater than 3.8.0, you can try the walrus operator

```py
out = np.append((window := np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(mylist, n)),
                 [window[-1] for _ in range(n-1)], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension for example? (use numpy arrays for faster iteration)

```
import numpy as np

mylist = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])

chunk_size = 3

splited_list = np.array([mylist[x:x+chunk_size] for x in range(0,len(mylist)-chunk_size)])
```

You can cast the result to numpy array or cast every item on the list to a simple python list.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way, it iterate the list in less than a second

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
for index, val in enumerate(myList):
    if index >= 3 :print("{} : {}".format(index, myList[index-3:index]))
```

The "list[index-3:index]" allow to slice the list from the nth-3 element to the nth element.

Hope it helps